# License issue with JRebel and Intellij Idea

Tags: intellij-idea, jrebel

I am using JRebel with Intellij Idea in Ubuntu. I have activated the plugin by pasting the code obtained from the website and it worked perfectly, but when i restart my IDE it is asking for the license again and i have to paste the license code each and everytime. How to solve this problem?

EDIT:- `jrebel.lic` file is not being created in ~/.jrebel/ folder

Comment: jrebel.lic should be created in ~/.jrebel/ during the activation. Are there any errors in idea.log? What is the full path to ~/.jrebel/ folder? Perhaps you have some tricky character in your user name and the path is just screwed with that character.

Comment: Did you fixed your problem? I'm having the same issue.

Comment: I've uninstalled the plugin and used standalone JRebel instead.

Answer (score 2):

I'm posting this workaround for those who are struggling with this problem.

Uninstall the jRebel plug-in from the IDE.
Install standalone jRebel from [here](http://zeroturnaround.com/software/jrebel/download/prev-releases/)

Now add the following in the VM options when running the program. **-javaagent:/opt/ZeroTurnaround/jrebel/jrebel.jar**

This is how i solved my problem, i don't know whether it will work for others too.

Comment: How does it solve the problem? You still need the license in .jrebel directory, unless you specify otherwise. Plus JRebel checks the .jrebel directory for jrebel.properties file (unless manually specified). So the initial problem must be related to the path of ~/.jrebel/ directory.

Comment: Still there is no jrebel.lic file in that directory. Actually I couldn't find such a file anywhere in my system.

Comment: Are you using my.jrebel.com then? In that case it will not be created, but rather persists the credentials to the service in jrebel.prefs file instead.

Comment: I think I am using that. I have a file with that name which contain some hex strings.